# Ray Datasource.iter_rows filling up local disk

Tags: python, ray

I am using Ray 2.6.3 from https://ray.io/. I have a custom Ray `Datasource` that fills up my local disk (in `/tmp/ray/session_2023-12-16_15-02-11_866522_3290839` etc.) when I call `iter_rows` to iterate through it.

It is implemented like so:

```py
import ray.data.datasource.datasource as rds
from ray.data.block import BlockAccessor, BlockMetadata

class CustomDatasource(rds.Datasource):
    def create_reader(self, path_list: list[str]) -> rds.Reader:
        return _CustomDatasourceReader(path_list)

class _CustomDatasourceReader(rds.Reader):
    def __init__(self, path_list: list[str]):
        self._path_list = path_list

    def estimate_inmemory_data_size(self) -> Optional[int]:
        return None

    def get_read_tasks(self, parallelism: int) -> list[rds.ReadTask]:
        read_tasks = []
        for i in range(parallelism):
            path_sublist = self._path_list[i::parallelism]
            if tfr_path_sublist:
                f = CustomBlockReader(path_sublist)
                meta = BlockMetadata(
                    num_rows=None,
                    size_bytes=None,
                    schema=None,
                    exec_stats=None,
                    input_files=path_sublist,
                )
                read_tasks.append(rds.ReadTask(f, meta))

        return read_tasks
```

The `CustomBlockReader` looks vaguely like this (I've ripped out all of the custom data parsing, etc. but the Ray-relevant bits are present).

```py
class CustomBlockReader:
    def __init__(self, path_sublist):
        self.path_sublist = path_sublist

    def __call__(self):
        for path in self.path_sublist:
            # sample_dict: dict[str, np.array]
            for sample_dict in custom_load_data(path):
                yield BlockAccessor.batch_to_block(sample_dict)
```

My `main` function is:

```py
def main(sys_argv):
    args = parse_cli_args(sys_argv)

    source = CustomDatasource()

    ds = ray.data.read_datasource(
        source,
        parallelism=8,
        path_list=args.path_list,
    )

    for i, x in enumerate(ds.iter_rows(prefetch_blocks=1)):
        if i in {0, 10, 100, 500} or i % 1000 == 0:
            log.info(f"""in loop {i}, {x["path"]}, {x["i"]}""")
```

When I pass in files that are larger the free space on the local disk, Ray fills up the local disk.  How can I change my code so that it only iterates through the files as-needed?